# What determines the Bone location, scale, rotation?

Tags: bones

i am trying to understand what blender uses to determine the position, scale and rotation of the visually rendered bones.
Referring to those: [image]
I am fairly certain it uses the IBM of the bone but would like to know for sure.
Another unlikely thing i considered was the vertices itself that the bone influences(i thought that blender would somehow use that data to determine the bones transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DNR: The location is determined by the coordinates of the head and tail of the bone.  The scale of the bone is 1, except the display scale of Octahedral bones is the distance between the head and the tail.  The rotation is determined by the head and tail coordinates and the bone's roll.

Blender uses two coordinates, called the *head* and *tail* and one other number, called the *roll* to determine the position of the endpoints of a bone.

A single bone showing the position of the head and tail:

[image: A single bone showing the position of the head and tail]

The transforms of that bone, also showing the bone roll

[image: The transforms of that bone, also showing the bone roll]

How those coordinates are used to determine the apparent scale of the bone depends on what you have the bones set to display as, and whether or not you have *Shapes* checked in the armature's *Viewport Display* properties.:

[image: An armature's Viewport Display, showing the types of bone display]

In your example, you have the default *Octahedral* display.  The apparent scale is set by scaling the default octahedral shape to match the length of the bone.  The length is simply the distance between the tail and the head.  In other display modes, unless the bone is displaying a custom shape, there is no scale.

EDIT: The bone's rotation is determined by the single *roll* value.  A bone's Y axis always runs from the head to the tail as seen here:

[image: bone showing all three axis]

The bone's roll records the rotation of the X/Z axis around the bone's Y axis.  Here is the bone from before showing its 30 degree roll from the top view:

[image: top view showing 30 degree bone roll]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I played around with the parameters a bit(Head XYZ and Tail XYZ and the roll) and what im really curious about is the Head, Tail XYZ values as those seem to be defining the position/rotation of the bone itself(eg which way the tail is facing etc) Also those values seem to be either relative to the parent bone or the origin(not sure as in my case the parent bone is at the origin) Anyway now im curious how those values are determined, is that something an artist sets and it's saved in the model format(glTF in my case) or does blender automatically compute them?

Comment: Quick gif of what i meant: https://i.imgur.com/CLoOm0k.gif

Comment: Okay so apparently a glTF file stores no other transforms than the IBM(inverse bind matrix) for the bones.. so now im not sure at all how those values get set in blender

Comment: It's a combination.  When creating the armature, the bone's tail and head positions are set by the artist, and blender creates the basic roll value as the artist moves the tail around with respect to the head.  The artist can ask blender to compute new roll values based on the bone's position in a parent/child chain or can manually modify the roll value.  Both of these are usually done because the roll matters in moving the bones around at pose time.

Comment: Hmm okay, but what i don't get is how it's saved(the tail and head positions of each bone) into formats like fbx, glTF. But i guess the transform of the bone(well inverse) is what stores it somehow. Thanks a lot for the explanations tho!

Comment: You're right, it's the export module that converts from blender format to whatever format other software requires.  The Head/Tail/Roll data is sufficient to determine the exact coordinates of the bone and it's "just" math to get that into another format.